# Flex mouse over area issue (custom button skin)

Tags: apache-flex, mouseover, custom-component

I created a custom button skin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
             minWidth="65" minHeight="22"
             creationComplete="GlassButtonSkin_creationCompleteHandler(event)"> 

    <fx:Metadata>[HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]</fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.graphics.RadialGradient;

            import spark.effects.Fade;
            import spark.effects.animation.RepeatBehavior;

            [Bindable]
            private var rectRollOverEffect:Rect = new Rect();
            private var radialGradientRollOverEffect:RadialGradient = new RadialGradient();
            private var gradientEntryRollOverEffect1:GradientEntry = new GradientEntry(0x8dbdff,NaN,0.7);
            private var gradientEntryRollOverEffect2:GradientEntry = new GradientEntry(0x8dbdff,NaN,0);
            private var indexOfRollOverEffect:int;
            private var myFade:Fade;

            protected function GlassButtonSkin_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void{
                parent.mouseChildren = true;
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,mouseMoveHandler,true);
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,mouseOutHandler,true);
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mouseOverHandler,true);

                this.addElement(rectRollOverEffect);
                indexOfRollOverEffect = this.getElementIndex(rectRollOverEffect);
                this.removeElementAt(indexOfRollOverEffect);
            }

            private function mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
                if(this.currentState == "disabled")
                    return;

                createRollOverEffect(event,0);

                myFade = new Fade(this.getElementAt(indexOfRollOverEffect));
                myFade.alphaFrom = 0;
                myFade.alphaTo = 1;
                myFade.duration = 200;
                myFade.end();
                myFade.play();
            }

            private function mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
                if(this.currentState == "disabled")
                    return;

                this.removeElementAt(indexOfRollOverEffect);
                createRollOverEffect(event,1);
            }

            private function mouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
                if(this.currentState == "disabled")
                    return;

                this.removeElementAt(indexOfRollOverEffect);
            }

            private function createRollOverEffect(event:MouseEvent,alpha:int):void{
                rectRollOverEffect.alpha = alpha;
                rectRollOverEffect.left = 2;
                rectRollOverEffect.right = 2;
                rectRollOverEffect.bottom = 2;
                rectRollOverEffect.top = 2;
                rectRollOverEffect.radiusX = 4;
                rectRollOverEffect.radiusY = 4;

                radialGradientRollOverEffect.entries = [gradientEntryRollOverEffect1,gradientEntryRollOverEffect2];
                radialGradientRollOverEffect.x = event.localX;
                radialGradientRollOverEffect.y = height-2;
                radialGradientRollOverEffect.scaleX = width/1.5;
                radialGradientRollOverEffect.scaleY = height;

                rectRollOverEffect.fill = radialGradientRollOverEffect;

                this.addElementAt(rectRollOverEffect,indexOfRollOverEffect);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up"/> 
        <s:State name="over"/> 
        <s:State name="down"/> 
        <s:State name="disabled"/> 
    </s:states>

    <s:transitions>
        <s:Transition fromState="over" toState="disabled">
            <s:CallAction target="{this}" functionName="removeElement" args="{[this.rectRollOverEffect]}"/>
        </s:Transition>
    </s:transitions>



    <!-- outer border --> 
    <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" id="outerBorder" radiusX="4" radiusY="4">
        <s:stroke>     
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="outerBorderStroke" weight="1" color="#ffffff" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- inner border --> 
    <s:Rect left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1" id="innerBorder" radiusX="4" radiusY="4">
        <s:stroke>     
            <s:SolidColorStroke id="innerBorderStroke" weight="1" color="#000000"/>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- fill -->
    <!--- Defines the appearance of the Button component's background. -->
    <s:Rect id="background" left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor alpha="0.5" color="#000000"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Rect id="backgroundTopPart" left="1" right="1" top="1" height="50%"
            includeIn="up,over,disabled">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="#ffffff" alpha="0.5" ratio="0.1"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="#ffffff" alpha="0.1"/>
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>


    <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
             text="Send"
             textAlign="center" 
             verticalAlign="middle" 
             color="#FFFFFF"
             horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1" 
             left="10" right="10" top="2" bottom="2">
    </s:Label>

    <s:Rect id="disableForeground" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
            includeIn="disabled">
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="#7B7B7B" alpha="0.6" ratio="0.1"/>
                <s:GradientEntry color="#aaaaaa" alpha="0.3"/>
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>


</s:SparkSkin>
```

The problem is that my hitarea seems to be wrong. When I click, it is OK, the area is right but with the mouse over event, the area seems to be different and smaller than the click area. I just don't understand why.
I even tried to change manually the hit area of the button skin by adding a line `this.hitArea = this.interactiveGroup` Where interactiveGroup is a group that contains the component borders but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its to do with you labelDisplay element of the skin. It has a right and left of 10.... if the right and left are set to 0, then the effect appears straight off, withough being too small.

Comment: Thank you very much! I though the labelDisplay would have had no effect on my hitarea... Anyway. It's working better now.